# c# linq filter Dictionary<DateTime, int> by predefined minimum time difference

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I need to filter the data from `Dictionary<DateTime, int>` to get only elements in which difference between subsequent `DateTime's` is 1 minute or more.

For example, in dictionary I could have such pairs of data:

```
var pairs = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>()
{
    { new DateTime(2010, 01, 20, 19, 05, 00), 10 },
    { new DateTime(2010, 01, 20, 19, 05, 19), 11 },
    { new DateTime(2010, 01, 20, 19, 05, 49), 12 },
    { new DateTime(2010, 01, 20, 19, 06, 05), 13 },
    { new DateTime(2010, 01, 20, 19, 07, 05), 14 },
    { new DateTime(2010, 01, 20, 19, 07, 55), 15 },
};
```

And what I would like as a result of filtering is:

```
<2010-01-20 19:05:00, 10>
<2010-01-20 19:06:05, 13>
<2010-01-20 19:07:05, 14>`
```

`DateTime` keys in dictionary are in ascending order so there is no need to reorder, but I would need it to be quite efficent because a lot of data is going to be processed.

Can you introduce me some nice piece of LINQ query to do that?

Comment: `DateTime keys in dictionary are in ascending order so there is no need to reorder` You should still sort them. According to the documentation, `The order in which the items are returned is undefined.` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). It works today, it could break tomorrow.

Comment: Also, if you want to be efficient, Linq is usually not the right solution

Comment: So do you want an array of arrays where the times are a minute apart?

Comment: @Roma only one, the difference in time between two subsequent poinst should be at least 1 minute (60 seconds)

Comment: Your example implies that the dictionary is ordered. First of all I suggest to use an OrderedDictionary as the order of elements in a dictionary is non-deterministic.

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen, As an output I need filtered out dictionary.

Comment: @rufer7 Yes I would switch to OrderedDictioary - however I still need this data filtrering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say this is a bad candidate for Linq. I would go for a straightforward enumerator:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> Filter(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> values)
{
    KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>? previous = null;

    foreach (var kvp in values.OrderBy(v => v.Key))
    {
        if (previous == null || (kvp.Key - previous.Value.Key).TotalMinutes >= 1)
        {
            previous = kvp;
            yield return kvp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just enumerate it and do whatever you need with the result:

```
foreach (var value in Filter(dictionary))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{value.Key} - {value.Value}");
}
```

---

*Just for fun*, a Linq version (please, please, please don't use it):

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> FilterLinq(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> values)
{
    KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>? previous = null;

    return from kvp in values
           orderby kvp.Key
           where previous == null || (kvp.Key - previous.Value.Key).TotalMinutes >= 1
           select (previous = kvp).Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that LINQ is a good choice here. It's usually easy to maintain and more often than not any performance loss is negligible.

Try this:

```
var filtered =
    pairs.Skip(1).Aggregate(pairs.Take(1).ToList(), (a, p) =>
    {
        if (p.Key.Subtract(a.Last().Key).TotalMinutes >= 1.0)
        {
            a.Add(p);
        }
        return a;
    }).ToList();
```

This gives:

[image: filtered]

Comment: Good to know that `Aggregate` is more powerful that I thought :)